# "The current user cannot create the diagram, please contact the administrator to confirm" in Galaxybase

Tags: graph-databases

When using the import tool galaxybase-load in Galaxybase, I encountered the following message: The current user cannot create the diagram, please contact the administrator to confirm.

Does that mean I need to ask the administrator for authorization? Do I need the admin's permission every time I build a map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is caused by the current user not having permission to create diagrams, which can be solved by using an administrator account or by contacting the administrator to adjust user permissions.

If you need to build graphs often, you can ask the administrator to adjust the user permissions, and then you won't need permission all the time.